# What is the proper way to mutate values from an imported sibling component in Vue.js 2.0?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application

I'm using the single-file component approach with Vue 2.0. I have 3 components `App` (parent), `AppHeader`, and `FormModal`. `AppHeader` and `FormModal` are immediate children of `App` and siblings of each other.

The goal is that when a button in `AppHeader` is clicked the `FormModal` visibility should be toggled. The problem I'm having is understanding Vue's uni-directional data flow. How can I pass an event back up to the parent (`App`) from `AppHeader` to let it know to mutate the form's visibility?

(AppHeader.vue)

```
<template>
    <header>
        <div class="app-header">
            <h1 class="app-title">Sample Header</h1>
            <a class="link-right" v-on:click="toggleModal()" href="#">
               <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>
</template>

<script>
    import FormModal from "./FormModal.vue";
    export default {
        name : "AppHeader",
        props : ['visible'],
        methods : {
            toggleModal () {
                this.visible = !this.visible;
            }
        },
        components : {
            FormModal
        }
    }
</script>
```

(FormModal.vue)

```
<template>
    <div class = "form-content" v-if="visible">
        <!-- Some form markup -->
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name : "FormModal",
        props : ['visible']
        //Also have data, methods, and computed here, but they aren't relevant to the example.
    }
</script>
```

I've certainly botched the concept of props in this example. I'm very confused about the correct way to use props when importing a template.

**Edit:**

Forgive me, this is my first day working with Vue. I initially left out a very important piece of information, my `App.vue` file, which is the parent of all of my templates.

(App.vue)

```
<template>
    <div class="app">
        <AppHeader></AppHeader>
        <FormModal></FormModal>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import AppHeader from "./AppHeader.vue";
    import Compose from "./FormModal.vue";
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                views : [AppHeader, FormModal]
            }
        },
        components : {
            AppHeader,
            FormModal
        }
    }
</script>
```

In summary, App is the parent. There are 2 siblings, `AppHeader` and `FormModal`. When a button gets clicked in `AppHeader`, `FormModal`'s visibility should be toggled.

I don't yet have a great grasp of Vue's uni-directional data flow and I'm not sure how to approach this scenario.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete.  Where do you actually render the form modal component?

Comment: You're correct David and I just realized that - I will make the appropriate edit.

Comment: @DavidL I just edited the post to show the complete picture. Good catch.

Comment: Vue does a fantastic job in documentation, I suggest you make sure you've gone through [the relative part](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html) before being sure you have problem understanding its data flow.

Answer (score 1):

In your app header you need to bind `"visible" data field` to a `"visible"` attribute in the child (form-modal) component. This means that `"visible "data field` in `AppHeader` and `"visible"` property inside the child component will be "tight" together and any change that is done to the "visible" data field will be reflected inside form modal.

```
<form-modal :visible="visible"/>
...
<script>
import FormModal from "./FormModal.vue";
export default {
    name : "AppHeader",
    data() { 
      return {
        visible: false
      }
    },
    methods : {
        toggleModal () {
            this.visible = !this.visible;
        }
    },
    components : {
        FormModal
    }
}
</script>
```

FormModal Template:

```
<template>
    <div class="form-conten" v-if="visible">
        <!-- Some form markup -->
   </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name : "FormModal",
    props : ['visible']
  }
</script>
```

The idea is that your FormModal listens to any changes of "visible" prop that come from it's parent. Think about it as a "readonly" variable (in FormModal).

Comment: Hey, made and edit. The FormModal template should have read v-if="visible" instead of :visible="visible"

Comment: @Robert i think you used it correctly, if you have `v-if="visible"`. Just keep in mind that props inside a child component are "readonly" variables, so for example, you will not be able to change it's value in parent (AppHeader) component.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're doing with the <form-modal :visible="visible" /> element. I'm not sure exactly where this fits in to the example. Also, if I can't edit the prop in my parent component how would I toggle the visibility? Sorry for the noob questions :/.

Comment: In FormModal you have `{props : ['visible']}` line which means something like "I allow prop named `visible` to be received by my component ". In `<form-modal :visible="visible" />` you are binding prop "visible" to the variable in your AppHeader scope, which has the same name (e.g. you should have "visible" variable in your data).

Comment: @Robert, ops, i missed an important part, you MUST have "visible" field in your data object, in parent (i've updated an example). You can update the state of your variable ONLY in the parent component, for the child component all values that have been sent into it as properties will be immutable. No worries:)

Comment: Ok, I feel like I get everything except for the <form-modal :visible="visible"/> step. Thank you for sticking with me and updating your post. Basically, every template gets 1 root node, and from what I understand including that custom tag is basically importing the template markup, which in my case should not be a child of the header. I've included it just for testing and followed your advice. Unfortunately I've yet to get my modal to show.

Comment: @Robert take a look in this jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/o72v99pw/ hope it will clarify how exectly it should work

Comment: You really deserve the accepted answer for this question and have answered my question correctly. Unfortunately being new to view I framed it incorrectly (sorry). App is the parent of AppHeader and FormModal. The question should have initially spelled out that the issue is changing a property based on an event that takes place in a sibling element. If you can update your demo to show this relationship I will definitely give you the check!

Comment: Your structure may not be the same from the OP's. `App` is the parent of `Header` and `Form`, so emit an event when Header's button is clicked to tell the parent to change `visible` is what he wants I think.